# Pyexcel get records from excel upload

Tags: python, django, pyexcel

I'm trying to integrate pyexcel into a Django project and trying to follow the example on the docs.

I'm trying to replicate this functionality:

```
import pyexcel as pe
records = pe.iget_records(file_name="your_file.xls")
for record in records:
    print("%s is aged at %d" % (record['Name'], record['Age']))
```

How do I go about opening the records via a file upload. I've tried to do this with no luck:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    records = pe.iget_records(file_name=request.FILES['file'])
    for record in records:
    ..
```

This line is bugging out: records = `pe.iget_records(file_name=request.FILES['file'])`

**Edit:**
The seems to happen in the for loop and is:

```
IOError: Wrong file name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [get_records](http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#django_excel.ExcelMixin.get_records) in the documentation.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    records = request.FILES['file'].get_records()
    for record in records:
    ..
```

If you insist to use `iget_record`, you could try:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    file = request.FILES['file']
    file_type = file.name.split('.')[-1]
    records = pe.iget_records(file_stream=file, file_type=file_type)
    for record in records:
    ..
```